# Translate Validation Constraint Messages on Symfony

Tags: symfony, caching, error-handling, yaml

In order to have error messages in different languages, I am following the instructions under this link:

```
https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/translations.html
```

I made the validator files with yaml:
For instance:

```
# translations/validators.en.yml
author.name.not_blank: Please enter the name of the author.
```

Notice: I tried the extensions yaml and yml

And in src/entity/Data.php

```
/**
 * @var string
 *@Assert\NotBlank(message="author.name.not_blank")
 */
private $author;
```

I just get the message "author.name.not_blank" instead of "Please enter the name of the author."

I cleared the cache like this:

```
https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/console/usage.html

 php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

I get the temporary message on the terminal "Clearing the cache for the prod environment with debug false"

So my questions are: Am I doing something wrong in clearing the cache?
I am using Symfony 2.7

Is there something I am missing ?

By the way, all other translations from files such as

```
translations/messages.en.yml
```

are functionning perfectly well.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you sure that you are browsing the website using the `prod` environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your code is fine:

now you can check additional stuff:

app/config:

```
translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
```

and be sure which environment are you in.

instead of

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

try

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

hope this will helps.

Comment: I was in dev mode indeed. Clearing the cache with php app/console cache:clear did not function. Since I did not know for the moment how to switch to the production environment, I tried opening the website on another browser and it functioned well. So it was a cache problem.